# How can I convert a int type to time type

Tags: python, time

I want to convert 20161017(int type) to 20161017(time type)

I try

```
import time
a=20161017

b = time.strftime('%Y%m%d',a)

print(b)
```

but It cannot work

additional question

in int type, i use 20161017 - 10000 = 20151017
how can i do this in 20161017(time type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strptime takes string as argument. So you have to first convert your `a` to string. And you should also use str**p**time instead of str**f**time

```
b = time.strptime(str(a), '%Y%m%d')
```

as for your additional question. There is `dateutil.relativedelta` for that.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
c = b - relativedelta(year=1)
```